# Water pump coming on on its own & how do reed switches sense water flow?

Tags: plumbing, pump

I live in a single floor apartment with a cold water tank fed from the mains, above a hot water tank which is fed from above. The outlets from the hot and cold tanks go into a pump and from there to the taps (faucets) etc. I'm not sure if it's a positive or negative system, the shower head is about a foot above the top of the cold tank.

Problem is that the pump comes on for a few seconds every 30 - 60 min. I am 99% sure I don't have any leaks. It still does that if I close off the two valves on the outlet sides of the pump.

This started happening a few years ago when I had to drain the tanks to do another unrelated job. At the time I was advised to replace the non return valves, so did all 4, was still coming on.

Now, looking at it again this year, I thought it was the pressure vessel attached to the pump as it would not hold air, so replaced that (last week), it's still coming on.

I thought I understood how it worked, there is a pressure sensor, so I assumed when you open the tap the pressure drops and the sensor turns on the pump. But then I read water flow is sensed by a reed switch placed outside the pipe, see pic. Unless reed switch means something else in the plumbing world, these are operated by a magnetic field, how can they sense water flow?

And, if the reeds control the pump, what does the pressure sensor do? I'm trying to gain an understanding so I can determine the problem.

The pump is a Stuart Turner Monsoon N1.5 bar twin (I'm in the UK/Ireland area).

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: speculation: a movable magnet along a hinge or track inside the pipe, held back by a small spring (or maybe gravity alone) against the flow direction, would move as water flowed. The magnet's motion/position would affect the strength of the magnetic field perceived by a stationary sensor outside the pipe. I made a limit switch on a rainwater bucket pump with a floating magnet along a rod on the side of the bucket, read by a hall-effect sensor on the outside bottom of the bucket; when the level dropped enough, the sensor saw the magnet.

Comment: @dandavis hi, yes that's what I thought of. But I had that pipe off when I was changing the non return valve and don't recall anything like that, but it was a few years ago. I might unclip it and move it up and down with a meter attached to see if what you suggest is plausible.

Comment: @dandavis Just tried it (was going to wait till tomorrow but curiosity got to me!) think you are right. I moved it down a bit and the pump came on, up and off again. A magnet must be floating in the water. Thanks! If you make it an answer I can accept it.